# cygwin tilde expansion not working in interactive shell

Tags: cygwin, tilde-expansion

For some reason tilde expansion in Cygwin is not working for me at the prompt:

```
$ ls ~
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory

$ ls ~/bin
(lists /bin not $HOME/bin)

$ echo $HOME
/home/myusername

$ echo ~


$
```

In the last case there (`echo ~`) there is no output (other than a couple of blank lines.)

I have `set expand-tilde on` set in my `$HOME/.inputrc` file. Is there something else I need configured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a recurring problem with Cygwin that, I believe, was tied to some upgrade bug a while ago and never resolved.

In any case, the solution is simple: open `/etc/passwd` in your favourite editor, and on the line with your username, between the fifth and sixth colons (the last and second-to-last), write in the correct path to your home directory, ie `/home/myusername`.

The relevant line in my `/etc/passwd` looks something like the below:

```
meand:unused:12345:54321:PCNAME\meand,S-1-5-21-4567891230-654987321-312456978-58252:/home/meand:/bin/screen
```

Comment: Just installed cygwin, and the file isn't there.

Comment: @nilskp I think Cygwin may have stopped using `/etc/passwd` now, so I'm not sure what the current solution for this problem is. Your best bet is to email the [Cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/lists.html).

Comment: Windows path to the file is /cygwin64/etc/passwd (if you are editing it using windows based editor, it won't see /etc/passwd).